# Getting specific data from axios get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the `href` of each individual image, like this, the `href` in bold I want to display.

```
{
  "collection": {
    "href": "https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=moon",
    "version": "1.0",
    "items": [
      {
        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12235/collection.json",
        "data": [ ... ],
        "links": [
          {
            **"href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12235/PIA12235~thumb.jpg",**
            "render": "image",
            "rel": "preview"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my code. Anyt ime I try to go further in the axios request data value, it says everything is `undefined`. I'm confused why I can't `map` out each link.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Api = () => {
    const api = "https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=moon";
    const [list, setList] = useState([null]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(api).then((res) => {
            setList(res.data.collection.items.map((item) => item.links));
        });
    }, [api]);

    if (list) {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{console.log(list)}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

const Example = () => {
    return <Api />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@1.1.3/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: *"it says everything is undefined so im confused"* Could you copy and paste the *specific* error you get into the question, as well as telling us where that error occurs?

Comment: I've copied and pasted your code into a Stack Snippet. It seems to `map` just fine...? The result is an array of arrays (since the source is an array of objects, and each of those objects has an array). Did you want some other format?

Comment: What's that with asterisks (*) in 
**"href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12235/PIA12235~thumb.jpg",**
does it break your JSON?  If I remove them it works fine. What is the console.log of 'res'?

Comment: @Gishas - I *think* that's just the OP trying to call attention to the `href` they want, but... :-)

Comment: @t-j-crowder Yes, I rushed a bit :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, I wanted to get the hrefs in each "links" individually, but when i tried adding an extra map to item.links.map() on line 9, it says "collection.items" is undefined. So far I can only only map all the links

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be two issues:

1. The result of your `map` in the `setList` call is an array *of arrays*. If you want a flat array, either use `flat` on it, or build it slightly differently. (Also, I would suggest not starting with `[null]`, just a blank array (`[]`) or `null` — given your `if (list)` later in the code, `null` makes sense.)
2. In `collection.items`, not **all** of the element objects have a `links` property, so the `map` returns `undefined` for those items. We can filter those out after the fact with `filter`, or provide empty arrays as a stand-in.

Here's an example with `flat` and the filter; since you seem to wan the `href`, I've filtered out any elements that aren't objects or don't have an `href` property:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Api = () => {
    const api = "https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=moon";
    const [list, setList] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(api).then((res) => {
            setList(
                res.data.collection.items.map((item) => item.links)
                .flat()
                .filter(e => typeof e === "object" && e.href)
            );
        });
    }, [api]);

    if (list) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Links ({list.length}):</div>
                {list.map(({href}, index) => <div key={href+"::"+index}>{href}</div>)}
            </div>
        );
    }
};

const Example = () => {
    return <Api />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@1.1.3/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

If you wanted to filter them out as you went along instead, you could do it with the nullish coalescing operator, providing an empty array as a substitution for `item.links` when it doesn't exist:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(api).then((res) => {
        setList(
            res.data.collection.items.map((item) => item.links ?? [])
            // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^
            .flat()
            // ...and then no `filter` here...
        );
    });
}, [api]);
```

Here's an example (using `||` instead of `??` because the outdated version of Babel in SO's Stack Snippets doesn't understand `??` — it doesn't matter in this specific case, we can use `||` instead):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Api = () => {
    const api = "https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=moon";
    const [list, setList] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(api).then((res) => {
            setList(
                res.data.collection.items.map((item) => item.links || [])
                .flat()
            );
        });
    }, [api]);

    if (list) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Links ({list.length}):</div>
                {list.map(({href}, index) => <div key={href+"::"+index}>{href}</div>)}
            </div>
        );
    }
};

const Example = () => {
    return <Api />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@1.1.3/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```